# How to handle if no rows returned in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the following piece of code:

```
sql.eachRow(query){
   def i=1
   println("$i --> $it.columnName") 
   i++
}
```

If query returns some records(rows), there is no problem.

But if query is returning 0 records then how should I handle it. I want to show a user-friendly message, such as *ZERO RECORDS FOUND*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rows = sql.rows(query)
if (rows.empty) {
    // logic for handling no rows
} else if (rows.any { it.name == 'something' }) {
    // logic for handling isExists == true
} else {
    // logic for handling isExists == false
}
```

I'm not sure what's your specific case is, but it may be a case that checking `name == 'something'` condition can be done straight away at SQL level with `WHERE name = 'something'`. Then you could get rid off one of logical blocks in *if* statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
def i=0
sql.eachRow(query) {
  i++
  println(i+" --> "+ it.columnName) 
}

if (i == 0) {
  println "ZERO RECORDS FOUND"
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am writing another logic after exiting from eachRow. So the answer you have given can't help me solve my problem.

I am looking for other way instead of using sql.eachRow ??? 

and 1 more thing, I am newbie to Groovy not programming .

Comment: @Prashant2329 Maybe asking your actual question will get you more accurate answers?

Comment: @tim_yates Actually, my query is sometimes returning some rows and sometimes it won't return any rows. and I am already using 1 boolean variable which is being set in eachRow block, which I am checking after eachRow block completes execution. So, I am looking for something else instead of eachRow method that would help me get rid of my problem.

Comment: @Prashant2329 it's not clear from your comment what exactly you're doing and what problem you have. show the code.

Comment: in eachRow block I am having :

`if (it.name == "something") {`
`isExists = true`
`}`

after eachRow block completes execution :

`if(!isExists){Callme()}else{DoThis()}`